# Download iPhone XS, XS Plus and XR simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am about launch my iOS game but before doing the launch, I would like to test my game with the latest iPhone simulators such as **iPhone XS**, **iPhone XS+** and **iPhone XR**.

Where can I download the simulators for these devices? In Xcode 9, I don't see these simulators.

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Xcode 9, I don't see these simulators

Correct. To get them, download Xcode 10.

https://developer.apple.com/download/